# Value is duplicating

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular. While trying to append a string to another string in array it is getting duplicated in second load. For example: I'm having a object

```
let exampleUser: ExampleUser[] = [{
  userId: 1,
  Name:'test'
  Desig: 'Manager',
  
}];
```

I'm trying to modify Name to Name + Desig. In first call it is working fine but in second call it is getting duplicated. I tried the below work around

```
exampleUser.forEach(e => e.Name= e.Name + " (" + e.Desig+ ")");
```

But on second call I'm getting the Name as 'test (Manager) (Manager)'. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Are you wanting to display the Name + Desig in your template or use it for other .ts level business type logic?

Comment: If you don't want to mutate your original array, you may use `Array.map()` to create a new array based on the original one. But as @cklimowski asks, if you just use it in the template (for display purposes), isn't it better to do it in the template?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. create a new attribute in your object (for example NameDesig) and assign it the concatenated value:

```
let exampleUser: ExampleUser[] = [{
  userId: 1,
  Name:'test'
  Desig: 'Manager',
}];

exampleUser.forEach(e => e.NameDesig = e.Name + " (" + e.Desig+ ")");
```

2. Don't mutate the original array but map it into a second array.

```
let exampleUser: ExampleUser[] = [{
  userId: 1,
  Name:'test'
  Desig: 'Manager',
}];

const exampleUser2 = exampleUser.map(e => ({
  ...e
  name: e.Name + " (" + e.Desig+ ")"
}));
```